# Quadratic Formula in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, quadratic

I'm looking for a theory file which contains the quadratic formula:

[image]

and of course it would be helpful to know the name of the lemma too.

I've already found this paper:

http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM040231.pdf

and I can copy-paste the proof in that, but then I'll have to rewrite it (because it doesn't copy perfectly). It would be better to have something that works straight away: maybe if someone knows where the theory file that matches this paper can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper you linked is very old and the proofs from it will not work without major changes.

Here's a short and simple proof of the theorem:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Complex_Main
begin

lemma real_sqrt_unique':
  "(x::real) ^ 2 = y ⟹ x = -sqrt y ∨ x = sqrt y"
  using real_sqrt_unique[of x y] real_sqrt_unique[of "-x" y]
  by (cases "x ≥ 0") simp_all

lemma quadratic_roots_formula:
  fixes a b c x :: real
  assumes "a ≠ 0"
  defines "disc ≡ b^2 - 4 * a * c"
  assumes "disc ≥ 0"
  shows   "a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0 ⟷ x ∈ {(-b - sqrt disc) / (2*a), (-b + sqrt disc) / (2*a)}"
proof -
  from assms have "a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0 ⟷ 4 * a * (a * x^2 + b * x + c) = 0"
    by simp
  also have "4 * a * (a * x^2 + b * x + c) = (2 * a * x + b) ^ 2 - b^2 + 4 * a * c"
    by (simp add: algebra_simps power2_eq_square)
  also have "… = 0 ⟷ (2 * a * x + b) ^ 2 = disc" by (simp add: disc_def algebra_simps)
  also from ‹disc ≥ 0› have "… ⟷ (2 * a * x + b) ∈ {-sqrt disc, sqrt disc}"
    by (auto simp: real_sqrt_unique')
  also have "… ⟷ x ∈ {(-b - sqrt disc) / (2*a), (-b + sqrt disc) / (2*a)}"
    using assms by (auto simp: field_simps)
  finally show ?thesis .
qed
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the lemma to prove work which might be published - in which case I'd need to include this proof with my theory file. How should I credit you if I do this?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed there's already a proof of this in `~~/src/HOL/Library/Quadratic_Discriminant`. Just use that.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect.